The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission
We have a project built with react-native and compiled for pwa using react-native-web.
we're getting an error when trying to play an audio:
The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
here is part of the code for playing the said audio, it's inside our audio controller class:
let playingAudio!: HTMLAudioElement;
let playtime = 0;
async play(path: string) {
    if (!store) throw NO_STORE_ERROR;
    const res = await get(path, store);
    this.playingAudio = new Audio(res);
    document.body.appendChild(this.playingAudio);
    this.playingAudio.currentTime = this.playtime;
    await this.playingAudio.play();
    this.playingAudio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        this.stop();
    });
}

according to our Sentry records it only happened in IOS Safari. I found out when I searched about the error that it could happen if the code is run without user interaction (like press). but I literally call the play function on onPress.
here is the component we're using this:
export const VoiceItem = memo(
    (
        props: FileItemProps & {style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>; onVoicePlay?(): void},
    ) => {
        const {
            itemType,
            time,
            hasMoreGap,
            style,
            onVoicePlay,
            deletePress,
            chatStatus,
        } = props;
        const controller = useMemo(() => new AudioController(), []);
        const pathRef = useRef<string>();

        const [state, setState] = useState<AudioPlayChangeEventType>({
            playState: PlayStatus.Stopped,
            playTime: 0,
            duration: 0,
        });

        useEffect(() => {
            controller.addPlayListener(setState);
        }, []);

        const getIcon = () => {
            if (canceled || isError) return 'Download';
            else if (loading) return 'Close';
            else if (state.playState === PlayStatus.Playing) return 'Pause';
            else return 'Play';
        };

        const handlePress = () => {
            switch (state.playState) {
                case PlayStatus.Paused:
                    controller.resume();
                    break;
                case PlayStatus.Playing:
                    controller.pause();
                    break;
                case PlayStatus.Stopped:
                    if (pathRef.current) {
                        controller.play(pathRef.current);
                        onVoicePlay?.();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        };

        return (
            <Pressable
                onLongPress={() => {
                    /*logic for actions bottom sheet*/
                }}
            >
                <Progress
                    max={100}
                    value={progress}
                    size={50}
                    hide={!loading || canceled}
                >
                    <Pressable
                        style={[
                            styles.itemButton,
                            {backgroundColor: tokens.PRIMARY.REGULAR},
                        ]}
                        onPress={handlePress}
                    >
                        <Icon name={getIcon()} color='white' size={18} />
                    </Pressable>
                </Progress>
                <Slider
                    {...SLIDER_PROPS}
                />
            </Pressable>
        );
    },
);


update: I tried adding an AudioContext and then await the resume function as @BGPHiJACK said. but still got the same error
async play(path: string) {
    if (!store) throw NO_STORE_ERROR;
    const res = await get(path, store);
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    await audioContext.resume();
    this.playingAudio = new Audio(res);
    document.body.appendChild(this.playingAudio);
    this.playingAudio.currentTime = this.playtime;
    await this.playingAudio.play();
    this.playingAudio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        this.stop();
    });
}


You can give this a read: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/ There is a bunch of references on autoplay policies.  Safari is a bit strict, try loading audioContext and resuming it on interaction.

@BGPHiJACK I did add an AudioContext and resume it but unfortunately did not work

I'm not going to lie to you, I ran into similar issues but my application required microphone so I did a camera/microphone check and it bypasses that. It's honestly weird.

@BGPHiJACK how did you achieve that?!
